# What's the closest thing to a nested dictionary (python) in Java?

Tags: java, python

I'm following a tutorial for a recommendation engine and the book wants to input user preferences and reviews using a nested dictionary. What is Java's equivalent?

Comment: Java's equivalent of a dictionary is a Map.  So you want a Map of Maps.

Comment: A dictionary in python is equivalent to Map in Java. So maybe a nested Map?

Answer (score 3):

A nested dictionary is a dictionary where the values of the entries can be dictionaries. In Java, dictionaries are implemented via the `Map` interface.

If your dictionary keys are strings (both the top-level keys and the second-level keys), and the values of the inner dictionaries are (say) `Widget`s, then you'd use a `Map<String, Map<String, Widget>>`:

```
//  +---------------------------- Outer dictionary key type
//  v       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-- Outer dictionary value type
Map<String, Map<String, Widget>> nested = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Widget>>;
//              ^       ^
//              |       |
//              |       +-------- Inner dictionary value type
//              +---------------- Inner dictionary key type
```

...where `HashMap` is just one of the possible `Map` implementations you might use.

Answer (score 3):

Nested HashMap is what you might be looking for.

---

*You can do it like this:*

```
Map<Float, Map<Float, Integer>>map=new HashMap<>();

map.put(.0F,new HashMap(){{put(.0F,0);}});
map.put(.1F,new HashMap(){{put(.1F,1);}});

map.get(.0F).get(.0F);
```